# Drawing a jug using JavaScript canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

```js
var c = document.getElementById("view");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.moveTo(100, 100);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(150, 60, 200, 100);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(150, 140, 100, 100);
ctx.bezierCurveTo(110, 150, 90, 160, 100, 200)
ctx.moveTo(205, 105)
ctx.bezierCurveTo(170, 150, 210, 140, 205, 200)
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(152.5, 240, 100, 200)
ctx.moveTo(100, 165)
ctx.arc(100, 140, 25, 0.5 * Math.PI, 1.55 * Math.PI)
ctx.moveTo(100, 150)
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(152.5, 120, 195, 150);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(152.5, 170, 100, 150)
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id="view" width=900 height=400 style="border: 1px solid red"></canvas>
```

on the above code, I was trying to draw a **water jug** but no matter how much I tried, it is not getting near perfect. Is anyway to improve my code?

Comment: I suggest using Inkscape to draw - https://inkscape.org/

Comment: Define "perfect". What do you expect it to look like? What specific problems are you having? This seems pretty good to me.

Answer (score -1):

You should move this into a function and use a point or origin. This way you can draw this shape at any pair of coordinates.

The issue is your second `moveTo` call. The starting point it not at `(x + 100, y)`.

**Note:** Be sure to call `ctx.beginPath()` first, before you finish up with `ctx.stroke()`. Also, if you are going to have a sequence of pathing statements, be sure to add a comment describing which part of the path is being drawn.

```js
const ctx = document.getElementById('view').getContext('2d');

const main = () => {
  ctx.translate(0.5, 0.5);

  ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);

  ctx.strokeStyle = 'hsl(0, 100%, 75%)';
  drawJug(ctx, 50, 40);

  ctx.strokeStyle = 'hsl(120, 100%, 75%)';
  drawJug(ctx, 200, 40);
  
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'hsl(180, 100%, 75%)';
  drawJug(ctx, 350, 40);
};

const drawJug = (ctx, x, y) => {
  ctx.beginPath();
  // Top-left
  ctx.moveTo(x, y);
  // Opening curve-up
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x + 50, y - 40, x + 100, y);
  // Opening curve-down
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x + 50, y + 40, x, y);
  // Left side
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(x + 10, y + 50, x - 10, y + 60, x, y + 100);
  ctx.moveTo(x + 100, y); // Here is the problem
  // Right side
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(x + 70, y + 50, x + 110, y + 40, x + 105, y + 100);
  // Bottom
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x + 52.5, y + 140, x, y + 100);
  ctx.moveTo(x, y + 65);
  // Handle
  ctx.arc(x, y + 40, 25, 0.5 * Math.PI, 1.55 * Math.PI);
  ctx.moveTo(x, y + 50);
  // Liquid curve-up
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x + 52.5, y + 20, x + 95, y + 50);
  // Liquid curve-down
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x + 52.5, y + 70, x, y + 50);
  ctx.stroke();
};

main();
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #222;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="view" width="500" height="180"></canvas>
```

Here is a more advanced version with config options:

```js
const ctx = document.getElementById('view').getContext('2d');

const main = () => {
  ctx.translate(0.5, 0.5);

  ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);

  ctx.strokeStyle = 'hsl(0, 100%, 75%)';
  drawJug(ctx, 50, 40, 100, 100, {
    mouth: 40,
    bottom: 40,
    water: 20,
    handleRadius: 25
  });

  ctx.strokeStyle = 'hsl(120, 100%, 75%)';
  drawJug(ctx, 200, 50, 100, 80, {
    mouth: 30,
    bottom: 40,
    water: 15,
    handleRadius: 25
  });
  
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'hsl(180, 100%, 75%)';
  drawJug(ctx, 350, 40, 80, 100, {
    mouth: 20,
    bottom: 30,
    water: 20,
    handleRadius: 25
  });
};

const defaultOptions = {
  mouth: 0,
  bottom: 0,
  water: 0,
  handleRadius: 0
};

// Draw from top-left
const drawJug = (ctx, x, y, width, height, options) => {
  const opts = { ...defaultOptions, ...options };
  ctx.beginPath();
  // Opening curve-up (to the right)
  ctx.moveTo(x, y);
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x + (width / 2), y - opts.mouth, x + width, y);
  // Opening curve-down (to the left)
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x + (width / 2), y + opts.mouth, x, y);
  // Left side (down)
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(x + 10, y + (height / 2), x - 10, y + (height / 2) + 10, x, y + height);
  ctx.moveTo(x + width, y);
  // Right side (down)
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(x + (width / 2) + 20, y + (height / 2), x + width + 10, y + (height / 2) - 10, x + width + 5, y + height);
  // Bottom
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x + (width / 2) + 2.5, y + height + opts.bottom, x, y + height);
  // Handle
  ctx.moveTo(x, y + (height / 2) + (opts.handleRadius / 2));
  ctx.arc(x, y + (height / 2) - 10, opts.handleRadius, 0.5 * Math.PI, 1.55 * Math.PI);
  // Liquid curve-up
  ctx.moveTo(x, y + (height / 2));
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x + (width / 2) + 2.5, y + (height / 2) - opts.water, x + width - 5, y + (height / 2));
  // Liquid curve-down
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x + (width / 2) + 2.5, y + (height / 2) + opts.water, x, y + (height / 2));
  ctx.stroke();
};

main();
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #222;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="view" width="500" height="180"></canvas>
```